# Auth::attempt doesn't work [Laravel]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I've looked through all other questions on this...

So I set up a userSeeder which autopopulates my `User` table:

```
public function run()
{
    $users = [
        [                
            "email"    => "email@myemail.co.uk",
            "fname" => "Nicola",
            "sname" => "Elvin",
            "password"=>Hash::make("password")
        ]
    ];
    foreach ($users as $user)
    {
        User::create($user);
    }
}
```

My table shows this is stored, and password has been hashed.

In my login function:

```
  $credentials = [
                "email" => Input::get("email"),
                "password" => Input::get("password")
         ];
    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
                return Redirect::route("user/profile");
     }else{
         echo 'wrong';
     }
```

I did a `print_r` of `$credentials` and it correctly displays my email address and password.

Yet it always shows up as wrong.  It doesn't ever validate.

USER MODEL

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

protected $table = 'user';

protected $hidden = array('password');

public function getAuthIdentifier()
{
    return $this->getKey();
}
public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}

public function getReminderEmail()
{
    return $this->email;
}

}
```

Comment: Have you checked that your `auth` config file reflects your Model and Table name correctly?

Comment: Can you show the `user` model ? Which field you are using for auth  username/email ? Did you generate the key in `config/app.php` using `php artisan key:generate` ?

Comment: yes table name and model name is correct

Comment: @RecoveringSince2003 edited to show user model.  Erm, no I don't think I did the key thing, what's that for?

Comment: there is a key in my app.php file so I guess I must have done

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  Embarrassingly, I had white space at the end of my email address...so it wasn't actually correct as I hadn't trimmed it...

Although the way I figured this out was by seeing the sql query that `auth:attempt` was running by installing a [Laravel 4 profiler](https://github.com/loic-sharma/profiler)

Comment: Glad you figured it out.